# Higher timeframe Indicator doesn't Paint to the last candle

Tags: pine-script

Hello Pine Scripters:)

I need your help. I am currently Learning Pine Script and I have one newbie Question regarding it.
I want my Indicator who can be set on higher time frame to paint until the Last candle of the lower time frame. The Bigger the Timeframe of the Indicator, the shorter and away from the last candle he is... :(
The Screenshot below is on 10 min Chart with 4 Hours set on the EMA (its the same with sma).

Thank you guys :)

TickerId   = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, ticker)
timeFrame = input(title="WaveDeltav2 Timeframe", type=resolution, defval="30")
MyEMA = security(TickerId, timeFrame, (ema(close, 2)) , barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(MyEMA, "EMA", color(yellow,75), style=line, linewidth=9)

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5asA.png)

Answer (score -1):

We can pull the higher timeframe ema in a variable using the security function. Then we can calculate live ema using the higher tf ema and current close.

In below example I have pulled higher tf ema in a variable called MyEMA. If it is not na then another variable called ema is set with this value. Else the variable ema is set with its own previous candles value. This way ema variable will always contain higher TF ema that was calculated till the last closed higher tf candle.

Then we use this higher tf ema and use the lower tf close on it to calculate the live ema.

```
TickerId = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, ticker) 
timeFrame = input(title="WaveDeltav2 Timeframe", type=resolution, defval="30")  
ema=0.0
MyEMA = security(TickerId, timeFrame, (ema(close, 2)) , barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on) 
if not na(MyEMA)
    ema:=MyEMA
else 
    ema:=ema[1]
plot(barstate.islast and not barstate.isconfirmed?(ema+close*2)/3:MyEMA, "EMA", color(red,75), style=line, linewidth=9)
```

Comment: (ema+close*2)/3 is not the higher timeframe MyEMA

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide explanation on how it is higher tf ema only. You can even plot it to test it.